# 2D map with stationary LIDAR

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a 2D map of a room. This is a project for learning ROS in the first place, so there's no robot involved. I just want to be able to make a map from either my laserscan data or pc2 data. I'm using the Scanse Sweep LIDAR, and I'm able to view live data in rviz. Can I use gmapping, and input static odometry data, or is Hector mapping better in this case?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306150/2d-map-with-stationary-lidar/) by [stianjoer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38088/stianjoer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdullahsindhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/38523/abdullahsindhu/) on 2018-11-14**:
Hi
I am also working on making a 2D map of a room kindly explain me some steps to follow they will be help me in my undergrad project
Thanks
Regards
Abdullah Sindhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With gmapping just adding a static frame for `odometry` isn't enough because you have paramaters like :

```
~linearUpdate (float, default: 1.0)
    Process a scan each time the robot translates this far 

~angularUpdate (float, default: 0.5)
    Process a scan each time the robot rotates this far
```

your map would be updated only if you move, and I'm pretty sure there are other params like that. You can check [#q63457](https://answers.ros.org/question/63457/gmapping-without-odom/), they already discussed about `gmapping` without `odom`.

So yes, `hector_mapping` is exactly what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stianjoer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38088/stianjoer/) on 2018-10-18**:
Thank you!